# how to alert message in sessinStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

I have a button on my update page. This button redirects and refreshes the page after sending sms

**I want that;**

If the user pushes the button and sends sms 1 time, do not press the same button 2 times unless the page is closed.

In fact, I installed the structure, but because the button response is redirect, my page refreshes every time and never falls into the following else. How can I solve this?

**Response redirect(in controller)**

```
 public void SMSGonder(int flowId)
    {
        flow flow = db.flow.Find(flowId);
        string meetingDate = "";
        foreach (var item in db.sp_get_meeting(flowId))
        {
            meetingDate = item.meetingDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
        }
        DakikSMSMesajGonder2(flow.flowPhone.ToString(), flow.flowName, meetingDate, null);
        Response.Redirect("~/flows/Edit?id=" + flowId);
    }
```

**href button**

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="btn btn-default" id="sms" href="/flows/SMSGonder?flowId=@Model.flowId">Sent SMS</a>                 
            </div>
```

**and JQuery;**

```
 $("#sms").click(function () {
            var $foo = $(this);
            if(!$foo.data('clicked'))
            {
                alert("SMS sent successfully!");
            }
            else {
                alert("You've already sent this sms.");
            }
            $foo.data('clicked', true);
        });
```

Comment: Basically, you want the user should be able to click the sent sms link only once before the page is refreshed/redirected ?

Comment: yes, but when the page is close, i want to get back the old page again. thx 4 comment

Comment: I have an idea wherein you can disable the link once it is clicked. 
However, this will not get the session of closed page.

Comment: Also, the session should be based on user or the sms sent of that item irrespective of user?

Comment: what is your idea

Comment: I have added in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the div and it's content (anchor link) as follows so that the user doesn't click twice just before the page refreshed.

```
$("#sms").click(function () {
        $("#sms").addClass("disabledbutton");  //disable the div and it's elements 
        var $foo = $(this);
        if(!$foo.data('clicked'))
        {
            alert("SMS sent successfully!");
        }
        else {
            alert("You've already sent this sms.");
        }
        $foo.data('clicked', true);
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Also, if you want a validation on session, you could set a flag for that particular item using REST API and the same message cannot be sent twice for that item.

Comment: The example you are working on works on a normal button. but after I refreshed the page, I want to press the button before the page refreshes I do not see the button pressed.

Comment: @YasinKızıltaş If you want a validation on session, you could set a flag for that particular item using REST API and on page refresh check if the flag is true and add the `$("#sms").addClass("disabledbutton");` code in that condition so the same message cannot be sent twice for that item.

Comment: but  i dont know how to use validation on session:( a little beginner in mvc